# Windows shutdown not working as expected

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to remotely shutdown computers in my lab with the commands:

```
shutdown /s /m 192.168.1.57
shutdown /s /m 192.168.1.56
```

Shutdown occurs properly when I run each command separately.  But when I combine them via:

```
shutdown /s /m 192.168.1.57 & shutdown /s /m 192.168.1.56
```

only one machine shuts down, then Windows gives an error:

```
The entered computer name is not valid or remote shutdown is not supported on the target computer. Check the name and then try again or contact your system administrator.(53)
```

Any ideas how to troubleshoot/resolve?

- same issue occurs when I combine the commands in a batch file.
- systems all running Win 7, connected to the same workgroup.
- bear in mind that I am not an IT professional.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Then why don't you write a line per command in a batch file? Or use `shutdown` in interactive mode (`/i`).

Comment: >> Then why don't you write a line per command in a batch file?
I did, and encountered the same error.

>> Or use shutdown in interactive mode (/i).
I did, and encountered an error.  Can't remember what it was, but it was either that I didn't have the proper permissions, or the window just closed without the shutdown occurring.

Comment: I removed the reference to DOS as this is clearly about Windows (the command line in Windows has nothing to do with "DOS")

Answer (score 0):

Another forum pointed me to a workaround/correct implementation.  I just need to put a "cmd /k" between the & and the 2nd command.  Still not sure why my ampersand combination didn't work.

Answer (score -2):

there is nothing like **(&)** to combined the command.. I don't think you can do it like this.

You have to write the address with separate **shutdown** command.  CMD doesn;t provide such a way to concatenate or pass array or arguments..

Comment: The `&` operator exists in the batch language and is used for conditional execution. `OP1 & OP2` means execute `OP2` when `OP1` finished. http://www.instructables.com/id/Conditional-Execution-in-Batch/

Comment: I take my words back.. let me clear what exacly i want to say.. I am saying u can not combined the command in a single line using **&** operation. Yes it exist in  batch but in a single line u can not pass argument line array using **&** operator.. Hope now It clear what I was saying..!

Comment: we can combined command with argument.. but i am saying we can not combined more then one argument with single command.. If a command expecting only 1 arg we can not pass 2 separated by **& operator** to perform the one task for each argument.  we have to write the command as well in separate line.. got my statement?

Comment: No not at all. `ping -4 -n 1 localhost & ping -4 -n 1 localhost` works like a charm.

Comment: right..!! its working..! I don't know where I found when it was not working... That might be an exceptional case for that particular command like shutdown reported by user... @Matten thanks to clear my doubt or I will say misunderstanding... !